# C# How do you use a for loop to concatenate an equation into a list?

Tags: c#

This program gets a list of health and damage values in separate lists.

Then an equation determines damage output for each value in the health/damage lists.

The problem lies in scalability - this program is not scalable because the lists are static but in reality the lists are going to change in size and grow, this code below can only handle a fixed amount of list items, I need help in using code that will make it dynamic so that the number of items on those lists won't matter;

```
List<double> hp = new List<double>(); //items in this list = 4, but it's meant to handle 100's of items
hp.Add(200);
hp.Add(150);
hp.Add(300);
hp.Add(50);

List<double> dmg = new List<double>(); //if this list had 100+ objects I'd lose my mind
dmg.Add(50);
dmg.Add(120);
dmg.Add(240);
dmg.Add(300);

List<double> timeList1 = new List<double>();
List<double> timeList2 = new List<double>();

var p1dmg = 50;

var ptime = hp[0] / p1dmg;  // 200/50 = 4
var ptime2 = hp[1] / p1dmg;
//....

timeList1.Add((ptime * dmg[0]) + (ptime * dmg[1]) + (ptime * dmg[2]) + (ptime * dmg[3]));
timeList2.Add((ptime2 * dmg[1]) + (ptime2 * dmg[0]) + (ptime2 * dmg[2]) + (ptime2 * dmg[3]));
//....
```

As you can see depending on the number of items in list hp/dmg (4), I have to create new variables 'ptime', 'ptime2', ... and 'timelist1',... this is not efficient and not good, what code can make this dynamic and it wont matter how big the list is?

Summary: the problem is not how to get a lot of items and add them to list 'hp' 'dmg', the problem lies in the equations used to add the answers on new lists.

Comment: Can you describe the equation for a variable N number of items?

Comment: var listcount = dmg.Count; ? this

Comment: @AdanChristo how p1dmg is calculated ?

Comment: What is the meaning of p1dmg variable? Is it always equal 50?

Comment: p1dmg is a static variable, it only has a value of 50 that does not change

Comment: @AdanChristo Does `hp` and `dmg` lists has always same size ?

Comment: @tchelidze no they might expand, this is an example of 4 items

Comment: @AdanChristo They might be expanded, but will they always has same size or not ?

Comment: @AdanChristo okey, did you try my answer ?

Comment: @tchelidze i did not understand your question until now, both lists will have the same size at a time, if the list is 100, both will be 100, your answer works but i have to think how to work-around the order of this: ((ptime * dmg[0]) + (ptime * dmg[1]) + (ptime * dmg[2]) + (ptime * dmg[3])); notice how it's [0][1][2][3], on the next equation it's [1][0][2][3], so you can see the indexes change.. trying to find out how to fix that

Comment: @AdanChristo do you mean how this line `dmg.Sum(d => ptime * d)`  will execute internally  ?

Comment: `Changing the grouping of addends does not change their sum` is this answer to your requirement

Comment: Algebraically speaking, you can even pull out the constant of the sum, because `sum (c * dmg[i]) = c * sum( dmg[i])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this way

```
  var hp = new List<double>();
  hp.Add(200);
  hp.Add(150);
  hp.Add(300);
  hp.Add(50);

  var dmg = new List<double>();
  dmg.Add(50);
  dmg.Add(120);
  dmg.Add(240);
  dmg.Add(300);

  var length = hp.Count;



  var timeLists = new List<List<double>>();
  var p1dmg = 50;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    var ptime = hp[i] / p1dmg;
    timeLists.Add(new List<double>());
    timeLists[i].Add(dmg.Sum(d => ptime * d));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Computing

[image: formula]

in LINQ using a `Select()` for the pre-multiply and then a `Sum` gives:

```
double sum = Enumerable.Sum(dmg.Select(d => d*ptime));
```

Then you can do

```
timeList1.Add(sum);
```

Comment: Hey there thank you for the enumerable, just 1 question tho: how do you get around the fluctuations in dmg[i], for example, dmg[i + 1] --> dmg[i +3] --> dmg[i+1], what im talking about is that [i] will change, sometimes it might be 1, sometimes 3, your enumerable set's a nice pattern that goes from 1-->

Comment: The result of the sum is not dependent on which index you multiply and add first, i.e. `(ptime2 * dmg[1]) + (ptime2 * dmg[0]) + (ptime2 * dmg[2]) + (ptime2 * dmg[3])` has the same result as `(ptime2 * dmg[0]) + (ptime2 * dmg[1]) + (ptime2 * dmg[2]) + (ptime2 * dmg[3])`

Comment: this code is genius, how do you solve this stuff with 1 line of code? it's unbelievable and thanks for the help

Comment: You probably want to accept @tchelidze 's answer since he dynamically computes `ptime` *and* the `timeLists`, so his answer his more complete than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would use a for-loop for this:

```c#
List<double> hp = new List<double>(); //items in this list = 4, but it's meant to handle 100's of items
  hp.Add(200);
  hp.Add(150);
  hp.Add(300);
  hp.Add(50);

List<double> dmg = new List<double>(); //if this list had 100+ objects i'd lose my mind
  dmg.Add(50);
  dmg.Add(120);
  dmg.Add(240);
  dmg.Add(300);

// I consider the length of hp and dmg are both equally long. So hp should contain 100 and dmg as well. Otherwise this loop won't work at all!
if(hp.Count == dmg.Count) {
    for(int i = 0; i < hp.Count; i++) {
        List<double> timeList = new List<double>();
        var time = hp[i] / dmg[i];  // 200/50 = 4

        timeList.Add(dmg.Sum(d => time * d));      
    }
}
```

Comment: both lists will have equal items, but the item count can change

Comment: I didn't test it, but that should do the trick. Eventually you can put more logic behind this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<double> hp = new List<double>();
        hp.Add(200);
        hp.Add(150);
        hp.Add(300);
        hp.Add(50);
        List<double> dmg = new List<double>();
        dmg.Add(50);
        dmg.Add(120);
        dmg.Add(240);
        dmg.Add(300);

        List<double> timeList = new List<double>();

        var p1dmg = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < hp.Count; i++)
        {
            double sum = Enumerable.Sum(dmg.Select(d => d * (hp[i] / p1dmg)));
            timeList.Add(sum);


        }
```

Comment: Beauty in a few lines of code :D, thanks everyone for your input